# What is the refractive index of Black hole?

Tags: optics, black-holes, refraction

Black holes are dark, dense regions in space where the pull of gravity is so strong that nothing can escape, not even light. But does black hole possess some refractive index? Is it optically denser or optically rarer medium?

Comment: Far enough away a black hole behaves exactly like any other gravitating body, so your question is far more general and it is answered by "gravitational lensing". A discussion of of the "refractive index of gravity" can be found e.g. here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.0633

Comment: Since a black hole is well black; Interesting question I have to say.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense, if you take the usual description, the refractive index of a black hole is purely absorptive (perfect opacity) so it would be something like $n_0+i\kappa$, where $\kappa\to\infty$.

Comment: Time slows as you go deeper in a gravity well. From the view of a distant observer, light stops at the event horizon. So you could argue that $n_0 = 0$.

Comment: @mmesser314 shouldn't $n_0$ increase as light takes more time (for an external observer)?

Comment: You are right. I got it backwards.

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself, light cannot escape from inside the event horizon of the black hole, and so any light falling on the black hole never comes out again. That means the black hole is perfectly opaque, and so it's meaningless to talk about its refractive index.

Comment: I disagree with you. It is not entirely meaningless. Metals for instance are also opaque (below plasma frequency), but we can still talk about their (negative) dielectric permittivity and (imaginary) refractive index.

Comment: This answer assumes that a black hole is limited by its horizon, but this is incorrect. A black hole is a gravitational field described by the Schwarzschild metric, which extends without limits in space and time. The gravitational field outside the horizon is a part of the black hole and certainly refracts light.

Comment: Traditionally people use the term "black hole" to refer to the area inside the event horizon. If you insist that it extends without limits in space then *every* body extends without limits, since (e.g.) the gravitational field of the Earth is described by the Schwarzschild metric too, at least outside of Earth's atmosphere. As for extending without limits in time, this may apply to the Schwarzschild metric, but not to any physically realized black hole.

Comment: "*As for extending without limits in time, this may apply to the Schwarzschild metric, but not to any physically realized black hole.*" - Not to the past, but the past is irrelevant. Are you saying it doesn't extend to the future?

Answer (score -2):

I think because the light cannot able to escape from the black hole so I think the refrective index of a black hole would be infinity because if the refrective index of black hole will be zero so the light will easily pass from it